# How to write in specific address GCHandle (HDF5 read)

Tags: c#, pointers, pinvoke, hdf5

I'm a beginner in C# and I currently use the HDF5 lib to read my HDF5 files.

I am in the situation where I want to read a specific row with H5S.select_hyperslab() but I don't know how to use the GCHandle class to write to a specific address of a 2D variable.

So I have a float variable [x,y] and I want to write the line from my HDF5 file to [i,0].

Do you know how I can do this?

The part of my code concerned:

```
        for (i = 0; i < C_NB_MAX_PARAMETERS; i++)
        {
            hnd = GCHandle.Alloc(m_correctedSignals[i,0], GCHandleType.Pinned);

            /* Get index of C_PARAMS_NAMES[i] in the file */
            datasetOffset[0] = HDF5_GET_PARAM_INDEX(pa_numbersOfParameters, pa_parametersNames, C_PARAMS_NAMES[i]);
            if (datasetOffset[0] < *pa_numbersOfParameters)
            {
                /* Parameter found */
                H5S.select_hyperslab(dataspace_id, H5S.seloper_t.SET, datasetOffset, null, datasetCount, null);

                /* Read the dataset. */
                H5D.read(dataset_id, H5T.NATIVE_FLOAT, memspace_id, dataspace_id, H5P.DEFAULT, hnd.AddrOfPinnedObject());
            }

            hnd.Free();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

For the sake of illustrating how this could be solved in C# using [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com) (sorry don't know how other APIs work), I will assume that your dataset is named `dset` and of type `float` of two dimensions (size 50x100).

```
// declare variable 'data' that will store values from the dataset
float []data = new float[100]; 

// read third row of dataset 'dset' using an hyperslab selection and populate variable 'data' with it
HDFql.Execute("SELECT FROM dset[2:::1] INTO MEMORY " + HDFql.VariableTransientRegister(data));

// print values stored in variable 'data'
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(data[i]);
}
```